# How can I electronically measure tilt/compression of a pliers or alligator-clip?

Tags: sensor, distance

I would like to electronically measure the width (really the compression/extension) to which an object's constituent blades have been stretched. Or alternatively, I could measure some other parameter which I can then map to the displacement by data calibration.

In particular, I am dealing with a miniature tool (a few cm long) whose outline resembles an alligator-clip (or pliers). So consider something like either of the objects in the below image.

**How can I electronically track/measure the below spacing to a resolution of about 0.1 mm over a full-scale extent of ~10 mm?**

I cannot think of any transducer or phenomenon that I could map to this movement and get such fine resolution. For example:

- Perhaps I can measure parallel-plate capacitance -- would that be accurate enough in this scenario?
- Or maybe I could place a spring between the two jaws and measure the compression -- but how would I measure the compression of the spring?
- CV isn't a viable option because I wish to make the sensor compact enough that that I can log the data wherever I wish.

[image: measure]

**EDIT:** Updated with illustration added based on @Michael Karas's Answer and @Matt Young's suggestion.
[image]

Comment: Attach it to a [digital outside caliper](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+outside+caliper)?

Comment: @AndreKR: Great idea but that would be a little too big perhaps. Ideally, I wish to make the clip itself the sensor and have some sort of transducer attached to either the top end or the bottom end of the clip, and log the data in-situ. Perhaps I'll look to see if there is some variant of that outside caliper which is more compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look into small strain guages. Strain guages are a resistive element that changes resistance in relation to very small changes in the longitudinal stress introduced into the senesor element. These are generally made of a thing plastic type carrier material with loops of resistive material printed upon it. Generally a sensor is comprised of two resistive elements in series like a voltage divider. These are then wired into a bridge circuit that is monitored via an instrumentation amplifier.

The sensors often are made up with a stick on glue to attach them to substrate. In the case of something like your allegator clip you could use two sensors just attached along the outside length of the allegator clip assembly.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the OP doesn't state what these things will be gripping. If the opening is to be tracked without an object being gripped, there won't be an strain the jaws and a strain gauge will provide no useful information.

Comment: @Michael: This is a great idea. But I'm trying to understand: Suppose I were to attach these resistive elements on the outside faces of the alligator clip. And let's assume the clip grips an object, say a cable of 6mm diameter. There would obviously be a force applied because of the object in between the clip arms, but longitudinally ALONG the surface of each arm, there wouldn't be any strain, would there? Or am I not understanding where the strain gage element is to be placed?

Comment: @MattYoung: Yes, the clip would indeed be used to grip rigid objects, and measure their thickness variation over time. The clip-like sensor in my case would be a natural way to allow for the object to expand or contract.

Comment: @OrCa You'll want to put the strain gauges on each side of the of alligator clip, outside, and right over the pivot point for maximum strain. Have two will give you temperature compensation. You'll also have to consider the non-linearity of the spring that holds the jaws closed.

Comment: @MattYoung: Something like the above? (See my new illustration added in the Question). But the gage elements moved closer to 'C' and 'D', so as to center exactly over the pivot point ideally, I suppose.

Comment: Responding to @MattYoung - Yes, The strain gauges would be able to be used to detect how far open the jaws of the alligator clip are. What you would actually be measuring is the stress of bending being imposed in the jaw arm of the clip being induced by the spring of the clip. Once this was placed into a system a calibration would be done to record readings taken from the strain gauge for several positions of the jaws such as [closed, 1/3 open, 2/3 open and full open]. These data points would be saved as reference points. Then during actual operation the sensor reading would be (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) taken and then checked what set of calibration points it was in between. Linear interpolation would then be done on in that range to determine actual jaw open position. Depending upon how non-linear the jaw position to sensor position actually was more calibration points or less would be required. Note that the strain gauge idea would not be useful for any kind of "loose" or "free" component measurement. It would be good to measure to bending stress in a piece of material being imposed by an applied force.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Your comments noted. Sounds like this will work well. Even if the strain sensed were non-linear with respect to the jaw opening displacement, I could perform a pre-calibration as stated.  Calibration would be easy using, e.g., a caliper's jaws placed in between the clip.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: As far as the actual gage element, how about something like this Omega 1-axis product, since I'll only be measuring strain longitudinally?: [Omega SGD-1.5/12](http://www.omega.com/ppt/pptsc.asp?ref=SGD_LINEAR1-AXIS)  (Although this particular one doesn't come with an adhesive.)

Comment: @OrCa - Yeah, that is the idea for a single axis strain gauge. You would have to experiment with which one would be a suitable size for your application. Notice in the picture you linked how the resistive element loops back and forth - that is done so that you get a multiplier effect for how much the resistive element is stretched of compressed. The one pictured places 26 elements across the stress zone.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Ah that's neat; didn't notice that-- I was wondering how they made it more sensitive to stress. (When I apply strain to a standard piece of wire, its resistance doesn't change visibly at all.)

Comment: @MichaelKaras: I would be taking advantage of two gages (one compressed while the other is stretched) in the sense that I could nullify temperature effects and also get double the sensitivity for each volt of excitation if I use a half-bridge config like in [this schematic](http://www.sensorland.com/Images/SG-007.gif). Am I understanding this properly?

Comment: @OrCa - In the case of the alligator clip type of scenario the two sensors would both be operating in the same mode (compression). To get one to operate in the opposite mode would require that you put it on the inside of the jaw arm where the clamping of the jaw tries to stretch material. --- This leads to the realization that the alligator clip will see stretching of the material along the sides of each jaw and compression only along the outside top (bottom) of the jaw arms. If your sensor is too wide and ended up wrapping over onto the sides this could lead to less net singal detection.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Got you. (Had forgotten that I was placing the gages on two separate arms). And thanks for the warning about the sensor width.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: And with all of that in mind, basically, the ONLY reason for the two gages placed on two arms is temperature-effect nullification. Whereas if I were to place four gages, one on the top and bottom of EACH arm, then I'd also be able to squeeze out effectively double the sensitivity per excitation volt.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at a flex sensor such as [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10264) from Sparkfun. Resistance varies depending on the amount of flex. You might mount it as a 'U' loop inside of your scissors so that as the scissors open or close the sensor flexes into a tighter or looser 'U'.

Comment: Unfortunately, these flex sensors and stretch sensors in my experience provide nowhere near the precision I require, and also there appears to be drift over time.

Answer (score 1):

A [micro potentiometer](http://www.czkennon.com/PRODUCTS/Column_172.htm) might work depending on your tool configuration. ... <sub>I'm terribly new at this</sub>